# Finding zip codes in each line of a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have this file where each line of the file consists of some text as well as a zip code in the format like 12345 or 23456-2345. I need to extract these zipcodes from each line. How can I do it.

The lines could be something like this

```
123 Some street, Zipcode, IL, USA
2ND AVE STE 4000,SEATTLE,98104-1075,USA
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Is that right, that the US state can come after the zip code? That complicates matters a little and it's not usual. And can the zip code really be the letters Z, i, p, c, o, d, e? I think I know what you meant but it helps to be sure.

Comment: Are those the only two possible formats or can the Zipcode be in `any` position in the string?

Comment: @minopret. The zips are only numbers.

Comment: @yu_ominae. They are usually the second last column but sometimes they could be anywhere

Comment: I guess you'll have to split the string, and strip spaces, then check each field for numbers only or combination of numbers and one `-`character.
Sorry I don't write shell scripts, so I can't knock and example together...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all the different possible ways the zip code might appear, I chose a couple constraints..

1. Zip code will always have 5 digits and will optionally have a '-' with any number of digits after that
2. Zip code will always be followed by any number of spaces and a comma

Assuming all the addresses are in 'ADDRS.txt' ...

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]*)?[ ]*,' ADDRS.txt | sed 's/,$//'
```

We use sed at the end to truncate the comma from each grep match.

Comment: This would throw a false positive if any field ends with five or more digits. For example, if "STE 4000" had one digit more, it would match.

Comment: Yeah you're right. There are just not enough well defined contraints

Answer (score 0):

With such a poorly defined question, and poorly defined file format, I don't think you can come up with anything more precise than "find any five-digit numerical field, with an optional suffix of a dash and four digits".

```
grep -oE ',[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?,' file | tr -d ,
```

This finds the expression between two commas, then trims the commas.

```
perl -ne 'm/(?:,)(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)(?:,)/ and say $1' file
```

does much the same in a single process using a backreference. It might be faster by virtue of using a single process, or slower due to the size of that process (probably worse for small input files?)

If you genuinely need to allow the field to optionally have leading and/or trailing whitespace, adapting the regex should be trivial.